# in z/OS Assembler, can I read a JCL input stream twice?

Tags: input, zos, jcl

Is there a way to read a z/OS JCL input stream more than once? (one that comes from a //SYSIN DD *).  I know I could cache the stream the first time I read it, and then read from the cached data, but I'm not interested in that solution.

Note: the language is Assembler

Comment: Which program or computer language are you using to read the SYSIN?  Try closing and reopening the file stream.

Comment: You can call C runtime routines from LE conforming Assembler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the language.  This answer provides an example in HLASM and a reference to the 'C' Language reference at the end.

For Assembler you'll need to `REWIND` when you `CLOSE` the `DCB`.  See the label at `FINISH` to see how this is done.

There may be other ways but this worked for me on z/OS 2.4

```
         PRINT NOGEN                                                     
* ------------------------------------------------------------------- *  
*                                                                     *  
*  SYSIN2                                                             *  
*                                                                     *  
*  @author Hogstrom                                                   *  
*                                                                     *  
*  Test to see if one can re-read SYSIN more than one time.           *  
*                                                                     *  
* ------------------------------------------------------------------- *  
R0       EQU   0                                                         
R1       EQU   1                                                         
R2       EQU   2                                                         
R3       EQU   3                 * Number of times to loop               
R4       EQU   4                                                         
R5       EQU   5                                                         
R6       EQU   6                                                         
R7       EQU   7                                                         
R8       EQU   8                                                         
R9       EQU   9                                                         
R10      EQU   10                                                        
R11      EQU   11                                                        
R12      EQU   12                * Base Register                         
R13      EQU   13                                                        
R14      EQU   14                                                        
R15      EQU   15                                                        
*                                                                        
SYSIN2   CSECT                                                           
         STM   R14,R12,12(R13)                                           
         LR    R12,R15                                                   
         USING SYSIN2,12                                                 
*                                                                        
         ST    R13,SaveArea+4                                            
         LA    R0,SaveArea                                               
         ST    R0,8(R13)                                                 
         LA    R13,SaveArea                                              
*                                                                        
         OPEN  (SYSIN,(INPUT))                                           
         OPEN  (SYSOUT,(OUTPUT))                                         
         LA    R3,3              Number of times to read SYSIN 
*                                                                        
GETAGAIN DS   0H                                                         
         GET   SYSIN,INREC       Read the next rec        
         PUT   SYSOUT,INREC      Write that bad boy out   
         B     GETAGAIN                                                  
FINISH   DS   0H                 Invoked at End of Data of SYSIN 
         CLOSE (SYSIN,REWIND)    Close SYSIN and rewind                                        
         OPEN  (SYSIN,(INPUT))   Open it up again 
         BCT   R3,GETAGAIN       Repeat the madness  
*                                                                        
         CLOSE SYSIN                                                     
         CLOSE SYSOUT                                                    
*
         L     R13,SaveArea+4                                           
         LM    R14,R12,12(R13)                                          
         XR    R15,R15                                                  
         BR    R14                                                      
 *                                                                       
 SYSIN    DCB   DSORG=PS,MACRF=(GM),DDNAME=SYSIN,EODAD=FINISH,          *
                RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=0                              
 SYSOUT   DCB   DSORG=PS,MACRF=(PM),DDNAME=SYSOUT,                      *
                RECFM=FBA,LRECL=133,BLKSIZE=0                            
 *                                                                       
 INREC          DC  CL132' '                                             
 SaveArea       DS  18F                                                  
                LTORG                                                    
          END
```

Assemble the above and execute this JCL

```
//SYSIN2   JOB (CCCCCCCC),'HOGSTROM',                                         
//             MSGLEVEL=(1,1),                                                
//             MSGCLASS=O,                                                    
//             CLASS=A,                                                       
//             NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                                 
//*                                                                           
//STEP1  EXEC PGM=SYSIN2                                                      
//STEPLIB DD  DSN=USER1.TEST.LOADLIB,DISP=SHR                                 
//*                                                                           
//SYSIN  DD  *                                                                
 REC 1 OF 3                                                                   
 REC 2 OF 3                                                                   
 REC 3 OF 3                                                                   
/*                                                                            
//SYSOUT  DD  SYSOUT=*                                                        
//SYSUDUMP DD  SYSOUT=*
```

And you'll get this output

[image: SYSIN2 Job Output]

You'll see the same SYSIN data repeated three times.

For a 'C' program this reference in the IBM documentation for the [C Compiler](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbcpx01/cbc1p211.htm) provides some hints about rewinding.

> To open an in-stream data set, call the fopen() or freopen() library
>   function and specify the ddname of the data set. You can open an
>   in-stream data set only for reading. Specifying any of the update,
>   write, or append modes fails. **Once you have opened an in-stream data
>   set, you cannot acquire or change the file position except by
>   rewinding.** This means that calls to the fseek(), ftell(), fgetpos(),
>   and fsetpos() for in-stream data sets fail. **Calling rewind() causes
>   z/OS XL C/C++ to reopen the file, leaving the file position at the
>   beginning.**

What you're looking for is possible but the implementation is language dependent.

Comment: My appologies, the language is z/OS Assembler.

Comment: @FierceMonkey added an assembler example

Comment: @Hogstrom Clean and clear example, thank you!